# Block Settings not applying to Zen sub theme

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I've created a Zen sub theme using the Starter Kit enabled it, and set it as the default (I've changed very little from the Starter Kit). If I go to Structure > Blocks there is only a tab for the Zen theme (which is enabled, but not set to default). I can set blocks into different regions and save, but the changes are not reflected on the page. If I switch to the base Zen theme, the changes are there, but switching back to my sub theme shows just the default layout.

I'm new to Drupal, so should the sub theme be inheriting the base Zen theme's settings, or should there be a separate tab for the sub theme? And what do I need to do get the tab to show up? I've gone through numerous examples and tutorials without finding an answer.

Thanks.

Comment: When you install Zen theme you will get a README file that describes how you can create a subtheme from the base theme. Make sure you have followed every step

Comment: I solved the problem, but don't know exactly what the issue was. I'll post some details in the morning for the answer, but long story short: something got corrupted and removing/reinstalling the themes seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: great it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, but don't know exactly what the issue was.

While troubleshooting, I noticed some Warning

> site:drupal.org Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   element_children()

As well as the tabs not changing names regardless of which themes were enabled. Disabled and uninstalled all of my custom modules, but nothing changed. Disabled and deleted all the custom themes I had installed, and the errors disappeared and the Block Settings menu started behaving properly again. I copied all the themes back in, and it's still working properly, so I am not sure what the problem was.

I will be reinstalling several of the modules and checking to see if the problem reoccurs, but for now all is well.